# Why does any try/catch past while loop cause Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, servlets, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver for an app on JSP. Anything I add that has to do with selenium, it gives an error. it only works when I remove the WebElements. Anyone have any ideas what I can do?

here is my code

```
 while(i < x)
 {

    i++;
    writer.println("\n\n"+"Number "+i +"\n\n");
    if(rs.next())
    {   

        WebElement acc = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("x_account_"+i)));
        WebElement desc = driver.findElement(By.id("x_original_"+i));
        WebElement inf_desc = driver.findElement(By.id("x_infringement_"+i));
        WebElement twt_url = driver.findElement(By.id("x_url_"+i));
        List<WebElement> link_in_twt = driver.findElements(By.name("x_target_"+i));
        WebElement link_in_twt_1 = driver.findElement(By.id("x_website_direct_"+i));
        WebElement link_in_twt_conf = driver.findElement(By.id("x_website_direct_confirm_"+i));
        WebElement report_another_twt = driver.findElement(By.id("more_x_link"));

        String ACCOUNT = rs.getString("User");
        String DESC = "Sound and video recordings as performed by the " +
                "artist known as "+rs.getString("artist")+".";

        String INF_DESC = "This account is" +
                " incorrect.";

        String TWT_URL = rs.getString("FB_TW_Link");
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            acc.sendKeys(ACCOUNT);
            String Acc = "Account: "+ ACCOUNT +" - Complete";
            writer.println(Acc+"\n");
            //output.scrollRectToVisible(null);
            Thread.sleep(timer);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            writer.println( e+" ID:14");
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------                                                           
        try
        {
            desc.sendKeys(DESC);
            String Desc = "Description: "+DESC+" - Complete";
            writer.println(Desc+"\n");
            Thread.sleep(timer);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            writer.println( e+" ID:15");
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            inf_desc.sendKeys(INF_DESC);
            String Inf_Desc = "Inf_Des: "+INF_DESC+" - Complete";
            writer.println(Inf_Desc+"\n");
            Thread.sleep(timer);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            writer.println( e+" ID:16");
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            twt_url.sendKeys(TWT_URL);
            String Twt_Url= "URL: "+TWT_URL+" - Complete";
            writer.println(Twt_Url+"\n");
            Thread.sleep(timer);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            writer.println( e+" ID:17");
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            for(WebElement RadioOption : link_in_twt)
            {
                if(RadioOption.getAttribute("value").equals("website"))
                RadioOption.click();
                String Link_in_twt = "Radio in URL: Click - Complete";
                writer.println(Link_in_twt+"\n");
                Thread.sleep(timer);                                                                    
            }

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            writer.println( e+" ID:18");
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            link_in_twt_1.click();
            String Link_in_twt_1  = "Radio in URL2: Click - Complete";
            writer.println(Link_in_twt_1+"\n");
            Thread.sleep(timer);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            writer.println( e+" ID:19");
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            link_in_twt_conf.click();
            String Link_in_twt_conf = "Radio URL3 Conf: Click - Complete";
            writer.println(Link_in_twt_conf+"\n");
            Thread.sleep(timer);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            writer.println( e+" ID:20");
        }

        if(i != x)
        {
            //try
            //{
                report_another_twt.click();
                writer.println("Report Another: Click - Complete");
            //  Thread.sleep(3000);
            //}
            //catch(InterruptedException e)
            //{
            //  writer.println( e + "ID: Report Another x");
            //}                                                                 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        writer.println("There was an error in the MySQL query! ID:26");
    }


}
```

the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at att.yet.petl.XmlServlet.doGet(XmlServlet.java:492)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

apologies for not giving enough info

line 492 is

`WebElement ack1 = driver.findElement(By.id("claimer"));`

```
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    MysqlConnect();

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        try
        { //note that the entire script is basically in one try/catch       
        int x =1;
        int i = 0;
        rs = st.executeQuery(" query is here");


            DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capability.setCapability("platform", Platform.ANY);
            capability.setCapability("binary", "/ms/dist/fsf/PROJ/firefox/16.0.0/bin/firefox");

            URL url2 = null;
            try {
                url2 = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url2,capability);

            driver.get("https://site.com");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

            int timer = 0;

                WebElement numOne = driver.findElement(By.id("owner")); 
                WebElement numTwo = driver.findElement(By.id("input_text")); 
                WebElement numThree = driver.findElement(By.id("comp"));
```

everything in between this is just a try/catch of clicks and sendKeys

Comment: Uh, format your code and show us your `XmlServlet#doGet()` method.

Comment: And point out which line of code is line 492 of XmlServlet.java

Comment: Can you put a comment in your code to show us which line is throwing the NullPointerException?  It also might help if you post the entire class code.  I'm suspecting that your WebDriver might be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this line throws NullPointerException

```
if(RadioOption.getAttribute("value").equals("website"))
```

according to documentation: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29

> java.lang.String getAttribute(java.lang.String name)
> .........
>   **Returns:**
>       The attribute's current value **or null** if the value is not set.

If the attribute is not set, the function returns null and the whole expression throws  NullPionterException.

try this:

```
if("website".equals(RadioOption.getAttribute("value"))
```